# Add / Delete Rows from Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have created a table in Twitter Bootstrap here

I want to be able to do 2 things with it

1. Delete rows by pressing delete icon - will delete that row
2. Add a new name by adding text (name) to input field and then pressing "add new row"

**DEMO** - http://jsfiddle.net/qxdz4/2/

Looking for a way to do this with JavaScript / jQuery

My Code

```
<div class="input-prepend input-append"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-picture"></i></span>

<input class="span2"
id="appendedInputButton" type="text" placeholder="Add New Name Here">
<button class="btn" type="button">Add New Row</button>
</div>
<table id="users" class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" data-pk="1">Mike</a>

    </td>
    <td class="taskOptions"> <a href="#deleteProject" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="modal" class="tip-top"
        data-original-title="Delete Row"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" data-pk="2">John</a>

    </td>
    <td class="taskOptions"> <a href="#deleteProject" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="modal" class="tip-top"
        data-original-title="Delete Row"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" data-pk="3">Mary</a>

    </td>
    <td class="taskOptions"> <a href="#deleteProject" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="modal" class="tip-top"
        data-original-title="Delete Row"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

#### Notes

- Clicking the delete button should delete the row
- Typing into the input field and pressing "add new row" button should add a new
          row to the end of the table with the Name filled in

Comment: use .remove() and .append() or .after() function for your purpose in jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily remove the row by doing this:

```
$('td.taskOptions a.tip-top').on('click', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

Similarly, adding a new row can be done as follows:

```
$('button.btn').click(function(e) {  

    e.preventDefault();
    var the_name = $.trim($('#appendedInputButton').val());

    var new_row = $('<tr>\
                         <td>\
                             <a href="#" data-pk="1">'+the_name+'</a>\
                         </td>\
                         <td class="taskOptions">\
                             <a href="#deleteProject" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="modal" class="tip-top" data-original-title="Delete Row"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>\
                         </td>\
                      </tr>');
    new_row.appendTo($('#users'));
});
```

Please note that it might be worth adding a more specific class name to the button (when clicked to add the row) to avoid any confusion. An ID would work just as well.

I've updated your jsFiddle with the additional functionality. You can see [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qxdz4/5/).

Comment: You should also note that you're using an old version of jQuery in the Fiddle that doesn't support `on()`. You should replace it with `live()`.

Comment: thanks, yeah I loaded that version to easily load boostrap js as only option in there for some reason. Guess I could add as a resource.  I see a little problem u might know how to fix. When I do add a new row, I am unable to delete it. Any ideas?

Comment: That's what I was saying above. You need to replace the `on()` with `live()`.

Comment: sorry to re-hash this. I tried updating the fiddle to use jquery 1.9.1 in the f/w options and I added bootstrap as resources. However I still have an issue with deleting newly created rows even though I am using latest jquery and `on()` - any idea where I might be going wrong, I can't see it? http://jsfiddle.net/UbpfK/2/

Comment: The Bootstrap you've included is throwing an error, thus preventing it from working. There's nothing wrong with the code you've updated. Here's the error > `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'webkit' of undefined` in `bootstrap.min.js:1`

Comment: ok thanks anyway, weird as in this version http://jsfiddle.net/UbpfK/3/ I use latest version of Bootstrap. Thanks for you help, appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you obtain each row's pk data (data-pk) attribute. That's up to you
On **document.Ready**

```
$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
function bindCloseButtons(){
    $("#users td.taskOptions a").click(function(e){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
}

function addTableRow(name , pk){

    // name column
    var row = $("<tr></tr>");
    row.append('<td><a href="#" data-pk="'+pk+'">'+name+'</a></td>');

    // close button
    var btnClose = $('<td class="taskOptions"> <a href="#deleteProject" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="modal" class="tip-top" data-original-title="Delete Row"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>');

    row.append(btnClose);

    $("#users").append(row);
    bindCloseButtons();
    $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
}

$("#addNew").click(function(e){
    var name = $("#appendedInputButton").val();
    var pk = 1; // TODO: set your pk here 
    addTableRow(name, pk);

});

bindCloseButtons();
```

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qxdz4/16/

Comment: Use `live()` or `on()` when binding.

Comment: Why? My answer's perfectly fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

First you create one method `AddmultipleInput()`

Inside the function,

```
    .AddMultipleInput = function (btnAddId, btnDelId, inputContainerIdPrefix, inputContainerCss, firstChildInputIdPrefix) {
    if ($('.' + inputContainerCss).length < 2) {
        $('#' + btnDelId).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

    $('#' + btnAddId).click(function () {
        var num = $('.' + inputContainerCss).length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        var newNum = new Number(num + 1);   // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

        // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
        var newElem = $('#' + inputContainerIdPrefix + num).clone().attr('id', inputContainerIdPrefix + newNum);
        
        newElem.children().each(function () {
            var idPrefix = $(this).attr('id').substring(0, $(this).attr('id').length - 1);
            var namePrefix = $(this).attr('name').substring(0, $(this).attr('name').length - 1);
            $(this).attr('id', idPrefix + newNum).attr('name', namePrefix + newNum);
        })

        // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
        $('#' + inputContainerIdPrefix + num).after(newElem);

        // enable the "remove" button
         $('#' + btnDelId).attr('disabled', '');

        // business rule: you can only add 5 names
        if (newNum == 5)
            $('#' + btnAddId).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

});

    $('#' + btnDelId).click(function () {
        var num = $('.' + inputContainerCss).length;

        $('#' + inputContainerIdPrefix + num).remove();
        $('#' + btnAddId).attr('disabled', '');
        if (num == 2)
            $('#' + btnDelId).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.icon-remove').live('click',function(){
    $(this).parent('tr').remove();
});
```

If you are using jQuery 1.7 or above, then use `.on` instead of `.live`.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan not with the version of jQuery he's using.

Comment: @BenM ~ fair enough; then let me note a semantic evil instead: using `.live()` is bad practice. There's a reason it's obsolete at 1.9, and deprecated two versions prior. `.delegate()` exists on the version he's using.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your delete links (like delete-row) and use something like:

```
$(document).on("click",".delete-row",function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
    $(this).parents("tr").first().remove();
});
```

Note: "$(this).tooltip('destroy');" would be better than "hide", but your fiddle bootstrap version doesn't support destroy yet. Also, you can set $("#users") instead of $(document) as handler for this event if you want, so long as the delete-row buttons are children of the handler the event gets delegated properly.

To add a line the answer of BenM should work perfect.

PS:

.parents(selector) function travels more than one level up the DOM tree, while .parent() travels a single level up the DOM tree.

.parents(selector) function selects all parents that match the selector, so in case there is a change you end up putting a table inside a table (accidentally im sure) you should use .first(), ensuring you dont remove the wrong row.

Edit: As mentioned by BenM, the previous code would not work with new lines, forgot the add part of the question, the new code should work.

Comment: There's no need for `parents().first()` here. Each element will have only a single `tr` parent.

Comment: Nice, but you should also update your answer, as this will only bind to elements currently in the DOM, and he is specifically wanting to add new rows, so your code won't function on those inserted after the binding has occurred.

Comment: Thats assuming a lot, but yes, ideally that is true

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you yo use following jQuery functions:

`on()`, `click()`, `remove()`, `append()`

Please do research on this, also look at the jQuery selectors in order to find how to select proper row.